# Reverse vowels of a string with the help of arrays and return a string

Tags: java, string

I want to reverse the vowels of a string.I want to do it with the help of an array,I haven't learnt hashsets.My function should return a string and I tried it by converting the string to character array..but then how to convert it into string ?? ..as I want to return a string only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a `char[]` to a `String` by calling a the String's constructor on it:

```java
char[] reversed = ...
String returnVal = new String(reversed);
```

Answer (score 1):

Covert the char[] to String

```
  char[] ch = {'g', 'o', 'o', 'd'};
  String str = new String(ch);
  System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [public String​(char[] value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-char:A-) method to convert a `char[]` into a `String` e.g.

```
char data[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
String str = new String(data);
```

**Note:** This example is also from the same documentation page whose link I have shared above.